# How to include lastmonth last week in this months first week using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I wrote a code that brings up Current Month Data and groups it by Week. This is great, but the issue here is that I want to also include Last month's Last weekdays in First Week for This month. The reason being the Current Month date is April 01st, 2021, but I am looking to group data for an entire week.
Here is the example

March Week 4 Starts on 29th March, which falls on Monday
Aprile Week 1 Starts on 01st April, which falls on Thursday.

So, If the Current Month First Week Number of Days is greater than Last Month Last Week Number of Days, how can I group the data in as April First Week which should be from March 29th TO April 04th.

The same shall continue for May, April Last Week has 5 days, and May First week has 2 days. Hence, the grouping should display data for Last Week Aprile and not in First Week May

Action Method

```
public ActionResult DisplayChart()
{
/*This Month Begin*/

DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
/*This Month Ends*/


var result = db.Chats.Where(c => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) >= startDate &&
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime) <= endDate).Select(x => new {x.MSTChatCreatedDateTime}).ToList().GroupBy(c => new 
{ 
Year = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Year,
Month = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().Month,
WeekofMonth = c.MSTChatCreatedDateTime.ToCleanDateTime().GetWeekOfMonth()
}).Select(c => new ReportVM
{
Title = string.Format("{0}/{1}/Week{2}", c.Key.Year, c.Key.Month, c.Key.WeekofMonth),  //chart x Axis value.
ChatCountCreatdDate = c.Count() //chart y Axis value.
}).ToList();
//return the data to the view.
return View(result);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public string GroupBy
        {
            get
            {
                if (Date.HasValue)
                {
                    DateTime nowDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    if (nowDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                    {
                        return "Today";
                    }
                    else if (nowDate.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") == Date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                    {
                        return "Yesterday";
                    }
                    else if ((nowDate - Date.Value).TotalDays <= 7)
                    {
                        return Date.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                    }
                    else if ((nowDate - Date.Value).TotalDays <= 14)
                    {
                        return "Last Week";
                    }
                    else if ((nowDate - Date.Value).TotalDays <= 21)
                    {
                        return "Two Weeks Ago";
                    }
                    else if ((nowDate - Date.Value).TotalDays <= 28)
                    {
                        return "Three Weeks Ago";
                    }
                    else if (nowDate.TotalMonths(Date.Value) == 1)
                    {
                        return "Last Month";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "Older";
                    }
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate your time and effort. Where exactly do I add this part of Code? Kindly suggest.

Comment: please suggest, how and where can I use the above code?